# Does WebCryptoAPI run on the browser or remote server

Tags: javascript, typescript, webcrypto-api

I'm developing a web application using typescript and webcryptoapi, I want to ask something related to bench-marking with webcryptoapi.

When we run a code line like this:

```
let encryptionPromise = await crypto.subtle.encrypt({ name: ENCRYPTIONALGORITHM, iv: context.ivBytes }, aesKey, plainTextBytes)
```

does this run in our browser, or does it go to remote server?
and secondly, when this code is run, what are the factors affecting the speed? Does our GPU affect this or internet speed for API call?

This might be very thorough question but I couldn't find a clear definition on their website, so wanted to ask in a simple sense here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, web crypto API runs on your browser.
2. The performance depends on your machine resources (CPU/Memory)

Comment: Okey I thought the same, an additional question.. If the performance is depending on our CPU and memory, why do I get a faster encryption and decryption times for the same application on my android tablet compared to macbook pro? I run the same code on the android tablet and the macbook pro 2017, tablet always beats. arent laptops logically faster?

Comment: Right, but there is an extra factor can affect the performance too the browser (Version and javascript interpreter) to make a fair benchmarking make sure you are using the same version of browser (in your case is kinda hard because you change the device tablet/Laptop but you can get a better result for your benchmarking)